# trouble configure jradius on Radius Server

Tags: networking, radius

I've installed and configure free radius on my ubuntu 12.04.
Now i want to configure my freeradius with jradius server.
I follow from coova documentation from here

http://www.coova.org/JRadius/FreeRADIUS

That step explain that i must add some configuration on etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf and /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default.

Now when i try to running my radius server i got error message like bellow :

```
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug: server { # from file /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:  modules {
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:  Module: Checking authenticate {...} for more modules to load
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:     (Loaded rlm_digest, checking if it's valid)
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:  Module: Linked to module rlm_digest
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:  Module: Instantiating module "digest" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/digest
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:  Module: Checking authorize {...} for more modules to load
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:     (Loaded rlm_preprocess, checking if it's valid)
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:  Module: Linked to module rlm_preprocess
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:  Module: Instantiating module "preprocess" from file /etc/freeradius/modules/preprocess
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:   preprocess {
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:   huntgroups = "/etc/freeradius/huntgroups"
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:   hints = "/etc/freeradius/hints"
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:   with_ascend_hack = no
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:   ascend_channels_per_line = 23
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:   with_ntdomain_hack = no
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:   with_specialix_jetstream_hack = no
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:   with_cisco_vsa_hack = no
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:   with_alvarion_vsa_hack = no
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Debug:   }
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Error: /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf[644]: Failed to link to module 'rlm_jradius': file not found 
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Error: /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default[71]: Failed to load module "jradius".
Thu Mar  7 11:56:26 2013 : Error: /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default[62]: Errors parsing authorize section.
```

What should i do to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if compile with the parameter "--with-rlm_jradius" while installing FreeRADIUS.
2. Check if instantiate the jradius in instantiate section in radiusd.conf
3. Check if set up your jradius config well in your radiusd.cong or in another .conf file.

These are the most common factors when your encounter troubles while installing them.

Okis

Answer (score 0):

rlm_jradius has not been marked as stable, and so is not available in the standard debian packages for the v2.x.x branch.

https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v2.x.x/src/modules/stable

You will need to build the module from source. Substitute the git checkout line for the version of the server you are using.

```
git clone git@github.com:FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server.git
git checkout release_2_2_0
./configure --with-rlm_jradius
cd src/modules/rlm_jradius
make
cp -r .libs/rlm_jradius*.so /usr/lib/freeradius/
cp jradius.conf /etc/freeradius/modules/
```

Note that rlm_jradius is not currently available in FreeRADIUS version 3.0, and that the v2.2.x branch will soon be deprecated.

Comment: hi, i followed your instructions, but when i do a `make` command on _src/modules/rlm_jradius_ i get a compilation error **fatal error: freeradius-devel/ident.h: No such file or directory**. Any thoughts?

Comment: That would occur if you hadn't run configure at the top level (not in the rlm_jradius directory).

Answer (score 0):

In case others run across this thread, JRadius support is included in the freeradius package for Ubuntu 12.10 - Ubuntu 16.  It was removed in Ubuntu 17, since they updated to version 3 of FreeRADIUS, and the JRadius support was not ported to version 3.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=freeradius